# reverse relation ship is not working in django models?

Tags: django, django-models

hai i have the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.intPartID FROM tbmstpart p, tbtrnappraisalquestion q WHERE p.intPartID = q.intPartID AND q.intTemplateID =4
```

my models are

```
class tbmstpart(models.Model):
intPartID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column="intPartID")
vchPartname = models.CharField("PartName", max_length=50,db_column="vchPartname")
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.vchPartname
class Meta:
    db_table = 'tbmstpart'
    verbose_name = 'PartName'
    verbose_name_plural = 'PartNames'

class tbmstsection(models.Model):
intSectionID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column="intSectionID")
vchSectionName = models.CharField("SectionName", max_length=50,db_column="vchSectionName")
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.vchSectionName
class Meta:
    db_table = 'tbmstsection'
    verbose_name = 'SectionName'
    verbose_name_plural = 'SectionNames'

class tbtrnappraisalquestion(models.Model):
STATUS = (
    ('1','Yes'),
    ('0','No')
)
intQuesID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,db_column="intQuesID")
intTemplateID= models.ForeignKey(tbmsttemplate,verbose_name="Template",db_column="intTemplateID",related_name="tbmsttemplate_intTemplateID")
intSectionID= models.ForeignKey(tbmstsection,verbose_name="Section",db_column="intSectionID",related_name="tbtrnappraisalquestion_intSectionID")
intPartID= models.ForeignKey(tbmstpart,verbose_name="Part",db_column="intPartID",related_name="tbtrnappraisalquestion_intPartID")
txtQuestion = models.TextField("Question",db_column="txtQuestion")
#txtQuestion = RichTextField()
enumRating = models.CharField("Rating",max_length=5,choices=STATUS,db_column="enumRating")
enumComment = models.CharField("Comment",max_length=5,choices=STATUS,db_column="enumComment")
intOrder = models.CharField("Sequence",max_length=2,db_column="intOrder")
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.txtQuestion
class Meta:
    db_table = 'tbtrnappraisalquestion'
    verbose_name = 'AppraisalQuestion'
    verbose_name_plural = 'AppraisalQuestions'
```

i tried in this way

```
parts_list = tbmstpart.objects.filter(tbtrnappraisalquestion__intTemplateID__exact=4)
```

but it is throwing an error

**FieldError at /opas/list_questions_test/
Cannot resolve keyword 'tbtrnappraisalquestion' into field. Choices are: intPartID, tbtrnappraisalquestion_intPartID, vchPartname**

thanks in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried this one as said by @Rohan. its working fine

```
parts_list = tbmstpart.objects.filter(tbtrnappraisalquestion_intPartID__intTemplateID__exact=4).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have typo of `__` in `tbtrnappraisalquestion__intTemplateID` rather you want `tbtrnappraisalquestion_intTemplateID`, with single underscore.

Change your query to

Assuming your `tbmsttemplate` model has `intTemplateID` as int primary key,

```
parts_list = tbmstpart.objects.filter(tbtrnappraisalquestion_intPartID__intTemplateID__intTemplateID__exact=4)
#there is no typo here, you have to do __intTemplateID__intTemplateID as your pk field in `tbmsttemplate` and FK `tbtrnappraisalquestion`  are same
```

Comment: i did as you said.but it is throwing an error Cannot resolve keyword 'tbtrnappraisalquestion_intTemplateID' into field. Choices are: intPartID, tbtrnappraisalquestion_intPartID, vchPartname

Comment: thank you its working. but can you elobarate tbtrnappraisalquestion_intPartID__intTemplateID__intTemplateID__exact=4.